# Blender crashed computer while baking cloth animation

Tags: animation, baking, cloth-simulation, performance

So I'm following this Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFOJ7ul19AE&ab_channel=Ducky3D

I'm following exactly as the video, the only difference is that I'm using an Skull instead of the ball.  The animation is supposed to only be of 20 frames n the video at 2:50 he bakes the clothing animation, when I do that, the program bakes normally, but always, the bake stops suddenly, and the % of the baking wont go up, and the computer gets incredibly slow, bordering crash, (although it always goes kind of slow and stutters a lot)

[image]

that's the only picture i could get because the program crashed after only adjusting the pressure as seen in the video. hope you guy cqan help me out.

The specs are:

Graphics: Geforce RTX 3060ti
Ram: 16Gb
motherboard: MSI x571-A pro
Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 3600TX 6-core 3.8GHz
windows 64bits

Answer (score 1):

With self collision and a complex object in the center, I can almost guarantee you're running out of RAM and your PC is having to do swap-file operations.

Check your *Committed Memory* (RAM + Virtual Memory) in Task Manager while doing a bake.

[image: im sorry that this picture is so huge]

In the short term, you can reduce the number of divisions in the mesh or lower the quality steps.

In the medium term, I can suggest buying a VERY cheap SSD (that you do not care to ruin) and running your page file off of it for bakes.

If you plan on doing this for long I'm sure you'll find plenty of reasons to upgrade your hardware, you won't need any convincing from me.

Comment: Thank you!i just bought his computer LOL, but I will have it in mind, what do you think i should upgrade first? indeed  the RAM was at full 16GB, and the program was in the ssd, i'm not sure how to run the page file but i'll serch it

Comment: It looks like a fine computer.  I just looked it up and your board supports up to 128 gb of RAM, so I'd maybe look at a 64 gb kit.  It's tough for me to recommend stuff right now, though.  The market is weird.