# All was fine and suddenly Out of memory?

Tags: rendering

quick question.

my laptop is gtx 1080 and i5 and he render any scene without any problem.
but when I got home to my stronger pc (rtx2080 ryzen3700) and opened the project, chose render view and tried to render it says " out of memory" and that it!

what is wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

If the laptop has an ssd it is able to handle page-file operations better (at the cost of some drive lifetime) and that seems to let you render things that you are otherwise unable to with your page-file on a traditional spinning hard drive.

Comment: thanks for replying so quick . It's weird because the project is on external drive anyway..so what is the solution in that case?

Comment: It's not where the project file is stored, but rather the hard drive the operating system uses when RAM runs low.  In task manager under performance you can look at the amount of committed memory to see if it is going over the amount of RAM installed in your system.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/208828/110840